# NLP POS Tagger For A New Domain

Tags: nlp, nltk

I am using NLTK and would like to use an existing pos-tagger which has been pre-trained and further train it for a new domain.

What I understand from Perceptron tagger operation is that it looks up the word in a file and if it cannot find the word, it predicts the POS for that word. Ideally I would like the tagger to predict the domain specific word. But I do not have regular annotated text for the new domain (I can comb through something like a medical dictionary to get domain specific words).There are two things I can do with the domain specific words:

1.I can write simple sentences like "I had angioplasty" and annotate them. This will allow the tagger to predict any unseen domain specific words with more accuracy. Will writing and annotating simple sentences bias the model compared to annotation from regular text?

2.I can directly include the word in the file. Not my first choice.

I also came across a document which used HMM for domain specific training but I am not sure it will work.

How should I go about it?

Comment: What do you mean by keywords? To train a tagger you need annotated text (full sentences). For domain adaptation you can simply re-train the tagger using the original training data with clusters induced over both in-domain and out-domain data.

Comment: E.g. of keyword for medical domain: Angioplasty - Noun.  Something like this. What do you mean by clusters induced over  both in-domain and out-domain data. What I  understand from Perceptron operation is that it looks up value from a dictionary and if it cannot find the word, it predicts the POS for that word. Ideally I would like the tagger to predict the word. But since I do not have annotated text, I am willing to directly include this word in the table.

Comment: You could iteratively develop your own annotated corpus.  Run the current tagger, correct the results, retrain with the correctly tagged data.

Comment: @triplee. That can be done but it is not scalable

Comment: I am not sure about the NLTK tagger. I would suggest to create a dictionary of your domain words with their respective tags. Follow the prediction of your tagger for all in-vocabulary words and use your dictionary if the word is not seen in the training data. I would also suggest to train your own tagger either using CRF or structured perceptron. Tagging is a structured learning problem, don't use vanilla perceptron for it.

Comment: The NLTK package I have downloaded uses Perceptron tagger. I understand the word doesn't need to be in the training data for making a prediction. It can be done using the context. With the approach suggested by you, it will have too much difficulty in assigning POS for a new domain specific word that it encounters. Ideally I would like to train it to handle any new domain specific word as well.

Comment: It would be easy to add domain specific words to tagdict in Honnibal's Perceptron tagger (NLTK). It just lexicon uses lookup for known words and does not need to use context if they exist in the tagdict. Add all your words to the tagdict, you will be done!

Comment: @riyaz. What happens if it encounters a new domain specific word? Will the accuracy of the tagger not be affected? I think it will. If I had done some training, the accuracy would be better.

Comment: in another vein, could you: 
1. train word2vec model with both the old and new domains. 
2. find the most similar entities to whatever you need to tag.
3. check the POS of the most similar and then use the most frequent POS for the new entity?